# Dagger2 Inject an Interactor into my Presenter

Tags: java, android, mvp

I'm trying to setup an MVP application, I want to Inject my interactor into Presenter Class instead of using the new keyword.

See Example below:

// Example presenter Implementation

```
public class ExamplePresenterImpl implements ExamplePresenter{

        private final Application application;
        private ExampleView exampleView;
        private ExampleInteractorImpl interactor;

        public ExamplePresenterImpl(Application application){
            this.application = application;
            // I WANT TO GET RID OF THIS AND INJECT INSTEAD.
            interactor = new ExampleInteractorImpl(application);
        }

        @Override
        public void setView(ExampleView exampleView){
            this.exampleView = exampleView;
        }

        public void callInteractorMethod(){
            // call Fetch method from Interactor
            interactor.fetchData();
        }

    }
```

// Interactor

```
public class ExampleInteractorImpl implements ExampleInteractor { 

        private final Application application;

        public ExamplePresenterImpl(Application application){
            this.application = application;
        }

        public List<String> fetchData(){
             // return value to the called function
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the interactor into the constructor of the presenter :

```
public class MyPresenterImpl implements MyPresenter {
    private MyView view;
    private MyInteractor interactor;

    public MyPresenterImpl(MyView view, MyInteractor interactor) {
        this.view = view;
        this.interactor = interactor;
    }
}
```

Then in your module :

```
@Singleton @Provides
public MyInteractor provideMyInteractor(Dependencies...){
    return new MyInteractorImpl(your_dependencies);
}

@Singleton @Provides
public MyPresenter provideMyPresenter(MyView view, MyInteractor interactor){
    return new MyPresenterImpl(view, interactor);
}
```

Or you could annotate both Presenter and Interactor constructors with **@Inject** annotation.

I made an example with a simple login page, you can take a look at it if you need :

**https://github.com/omaflak/Dagger2-MVP**

Answer (score 0):

You should inject presenter into View(e.g. into Activity) class. Create a module like ExampleModule and a component like ExampleComponent, which will provide the presenter. Presenter should have a constructor that expects all needed dependencies. In this example, dependencies are Application and the interactor

Comment: No, you don't. You should pass the interactor into the contsturctor, so that you could mock it and test the presenter